# Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 not recognized in BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, bios

A computer with a Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 failed, so I found another computer to replace it. I was going to swap out the hard drives, but when I put the Seagate in the new computer, it doesn't recognize it in the BIOS. I put it in another machine that recognized it just fine.

It's a fine SATA cable, and I've reset the CMOS battery, reseated the video card and memory, I've tried everything. What could this possibly be?

Comment: Some bios's have to have the sata port enabled before it will communicate with the drive. Have a look at all the bios settings.

Comment: Do ANY SATA drives work in this machine?

Comment: Can you be a litlte more specific than "I've tried everything"?  What's 'everything'?  Did you try a different cable? What's the motherboard make/model in question?